# How to send email to a selected id in android app?

Tags: android

This method is working for a specific email but I want it to dynamically populate when a certain user is selected.

Any ideas?? 
This is my code for details activity

I have a listview which on click displays details of a particular person and I have a button in that details activity which after clicking should populate the particular email id.

```
public class AgentDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView a_id;
private TextView a_fname;
private TextView a_lname;
private TextView a_phone;
private TextView a_email;
private TextView a_position;
private ImageButton sendEmail;
```

private String JSON_STRING;

```
private String id;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_agent_details);


    Intent intent = getIntent();

    id = intent.getStringExtra(Config.AGT_ID);

    a_id = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.a_id);
    a_fname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.a_fname);
    a_lname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.a_lname);
    a_phone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.a_phone);
    a_email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.a_email);
    a_position = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.a_position);
    sendEmail = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sendEmail);


    a_id.setText(id);
    a_fname.setText(intent.getStringExtra(Config.TAG_FNAME));
    a_lname.setText(intent.getStringExtra(Config.TAG_LNAME));
    a_phone.setText(intent.getStringExtra(Config.TAG_PHONE));
    a_email.setText(intent.getStringExtra(Config.TAG_EMAIL));
    a_position.setText(intent.getStringExtra(Config.TAG_POSITION));


    getAgent();
}

public void process(View view)
{

    Intent intent = null, chooser = null;

        if(view.getId()== R.id.sendEmail)
        {

            intent = new Intent(intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
            String[] to = {intent.setText(intent.getStringExtra(Config.TAG_EMAIL))};

            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Booking Request");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Need more information about booking");
            intent.setType("message/rfc822");//need for MIME message type
            chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"); //selects the in-build email app
            startActivity(chooser);
        }

    }




private void getAgent(){
    class GetAgent extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{
        ProgressDialog loading;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(AgentDetails.this,"Fetching...","Wait...",false,false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            showAgent(s);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String s = rh.sendGetRequestParam(Config.URL_GET_AGT,id);
            return s;
        }
    }
    GetAgent ga = new GetAgent();
    ga.execute();
}

private void showAgent(String json){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(0);
        String fname = c.getString(Config.TAG_FNAME);
        String lname = c.getString(Config.TAG_LNAME);
        String phone = c.getString(Config.TAG_PHONE);
        String email = c.getString(Config.TAG_EMAIL);
        String position = c.getString(Config.TAG_POSITION);


        a_fname.setText(fname);
        a_lname.setText(lname);
        a_phone.setText(phone);
        a_email.setText(email);
        a_position.setText(position);



    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/*@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == sendEmail)
    {

    }
}*/
```

}

Comment: Where is the string coming from for `intent.getStringExtra`? You never put a string into the Intent

Comment: @cricket_007 it's coming from json array

Comment: Umm, no it isn't. A few line before that you have an empty Intent... `intent = new Intent();`. Please show a [mcve]

Comment: are you calling this from another activity or it is in the same activity?

Comment: Assuming this is in an Activity, I think you wanted getIntent().getStringExtra(Config.TAG_EMAIL)

Comment: @GabeSechan  I just posted the code if that helps

Comment: You are making a new `intent` variable in the `process` method. I don't see how you expect this code to work.

Comment: @cricket_007 so what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: @Pooya same activity

Comment: You need to replace `intent.getStringExtra(Config.TAG_EMAIL))` with the correct String. I don't know where you want to get that from, though

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
String[] to = {intent.setText(intent.getStringExtra(Config.TAG_EMAIL))};
```

to:

```
String to = getIntent().getStringExtra(Config.TAG_EMAIL);
```

Comment: probably you are not passing data to the current intent correctly then. Check the activity which calls this activity and search for line: "putExtraString(Config.TAG_EMAIL,something)"

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is the following code:

```
String[] to = {a_email.getText().toString()};
```

it fetches the value from the a_email(textview) into the string which is further passed to

```
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
```